# How to display float elements in one line without tables

Tags: html, css

I want to display float elements in one line without using tables. When a user resize the window the elements change line but I do not want.

The HTML code which I use is:

```
<ul class='regul'>
<li>First name:</li>
<li>Last name:</li>
<li>Email:</li>
<li>Confirm email:</li>
<li>Password:</li>
<li>Confirm password:</li>
<li>Sex:</li>
<li>Date of birth:</li>
<li><input class='button' type='submit' name='action' value='Register' /></li>
</ul>
<ul class='regul'>
<li><input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='lname' id='lname' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='email' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='cemail' /></li>
<li><input type='password' name='pass' /></li>
<li><input type='password' name='cpass' /></li>
<li><select name='sex'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></li>
<li>
<input type='text' name='day' size='2' maxlength='2' />
<input type='text' name='month' size='2' maxlength='2' />
<input type='text' name='year' size='4' maxlength='4' />
</li>
</ul>
```

My website is http://greek.netii.net/.

Which css code should I use?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yikes. Please change your markup. Labels for inputs should be (a) near the input they relate to and (b) marked up with the `<label>` element (with a suitable `for` attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
<style>
.regul{
float:left;
list-style:none;
}
.regul li{
height:25px;
width:150px;
}
</style>
<div style="width:500px;clear:both;">
<ul class='regul'>
<li>First name:</li>
<li>Last name:</li>
<li>Email:</li>
<li>Confirm email:</li>
<li>Password:</li>
<li>Confirm password:</li>
<li>Sex:</li>
<li>Date of birth:</li>
<li><input class='button' type='submit' name='action' value='Register' /></li>
</ul>
<ul class='regul'>
<li><input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='lname' id='lname' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='email' /></li>
<li><input type='text' name='cemail' /></li>
<li><input type='password' name='pass' /></li>
<li><input type='password' name='cpass' /></li>
<li><select name='sex'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></li>
<li>
<input type='text' name='day' size='2' maxlength='2' />
<input type='text' name='month' size='2' maxlength='2' />
<input type='text' name='year' size='4' maxlength='4' />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Still, as @Quentin mentionned above, he should probably use <label> tags.

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left`, and then add a `style='clear:both'`to some element afterwards